# CentOS 7 - Subversion Update to 1.8

Tags: linux, svn, centos, yum

I am running CentOS 7 and i installed subversion from the standard repo, so i have 1.7 now. But I want to update to 1.8 from the WanDisco Repo:

```
[WandiscoSVN]
name=Wandisco SVN Repo
baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

But all the time i run "sudo yum update" i get this error:
How can i solve it?

```
Transaction check error:
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_client-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_delta-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_diff-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs_base-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs_fs-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs_util-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_ra-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_ra_local-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_ra_svn-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_repos-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_subr-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libsvn_wc-1.so.0.0.0 from install of subversion-1.8.11-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package subversion-libs-1.7.14-7.el7_1.1.x86_64
```

greets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by removing subversion and subversion-libs. They you can install subversion and the one from WandiscoSVN repo will be installed.

I would heavily advise against pulling third-party repos not recommended on https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories as you might get worse issues than the one here. subversion coming from the CentOS repo is split into subversion, subversion-libs, etc..., while the one from WandiscoSVN doesn't have subversion-libs. The issue will arise when you install a package that depends upon subversion-libs and all hell will break loose just because WandiscoSVN maintainer didn't correctly SPEC his package.

Answer (score 0):

Thx, removing it via sudo yum remove subversion-libs.x86_64 subversion worked out!

I didn't know this link from centos thanks for that!

- Question answered -